# ¿Como generar un documento .php con una clase dentro?

Tags: php

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de crear un documento PHP con una clase, por ejemplo: cuando en laravel uso el comando `php artisan make:controller UnControlador`, este genera un archivo que se llama *Uncontrolador.php* y dentro tiene una clase con cierta estructura.

¿Existe alguna manera de realizar esto con codigo PHP?

PD: estuve utilizando utilizando `fopen()`y `fwrite` para crear los archivos y escribir en ellos, pero me parece muy engorroso.

Comment: De ser posible lo es, pues Laravel esta escrito en PHP así que dicha funcionalidad esta escrita en ese lenguaje

Comment: Puedes armar todo el contenido usando cadenas y, al final, guardar con [file_put_contents($archivo, $contenido)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php)